# There appears to be no ground - what do I do?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ground

[image][image]
[image]

Hi!

Trying to change a light switch in my house. I am Chicago within city limits.

House is pretty old...it was “gut rehabbed” in the 80s but that doesn’t really mean anything. Actual building been here since 50s/60s.

Anyway, there doesn’t appear to be any ground wire. So what do I do with the ground wire I have on the switch I’ve bought. And is this lack of ground a huge issue that I need to get resolved? I’ve lived here over a year and get occasional shock in basement (but only during winter so put this down to static given it’s the dryest part of house). I attached some pictures to show what I’m dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

This work is of an age when it should've been built grounded.

This appears to use the **conduit wiring method**.  And this is metal conduit, probably EMT, so **the metal conduit provides the grounding path**.  This connection is in fact grounded.

That, by itself, does not bring ground to the device.  However, since this is a switch, it is automatically grounded via the metal mounting screws.

That is not allowed for receptacles (sockets). For that, you need to run a wire from the metal box.  The best way is to find a hole in the back of the box which is tapped #10-32, and is made for a ground wire.  They make special green #10-32 ground screws with optional pigtails, though any 10-32 screw will do.  Don't use a sheetmetal screw unless it's tapped 10-32.

Comment: Thank you @harper. That is a relief!

Comment: Do outlets with a self-grounding tab not meet the requirement?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Depends how well it makes contact. Relevant thing is the screw thread alone is not a valid ground path **for receptacles**... what's required is hard, flush metal-metal contact with the box metal without paint debris, rust, or those little plastic squares that capture the screws getting in the way.  If the tab accomplishes that, good enough.